# Docker compose - secrets Additional property secrets is not allowed

Tags: docker-compose, docker-secrets

docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.11.1, build 7c5d5e4

I have secret 'my_secret_data' added to my swarm cluster:

The start of my compose file looks like:

```
version: "3.1"
secrets:
  my_secret_data:
    external: true
services:
  master:
    image: jenkins-master
    secrets:
     - my_secret_data
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
     - "50000:50000"
```

'docker stack deploy' continually gives the error:

secrets Additional property secrets is not allowed

I have followed [how do you manage secret values with docker-compose v3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42139605/how-do-you-manage-secret-values-with-docker-compose-v3-1) to the letter as far as I can tell and have the correct versions installed but keep getting the above error. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shot in the dark: are you sure your white space is 100% correct? Also, should it not be version "3", not "3.1"?

Comment: Aargh, never mind, I just hit the exact same issue.

Comment: Ronan, I just changed compose file version to 3.1, and it seems happy. What version of docker are you running?

Comment: Hi, upgraded to 1.13.1 and all working. Thought we were on the latest version. thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Change compose file version to latest version.

In short, version '3' is not resolved to the latest '3.x' version. Find what the latest version is here https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#compose-and-docker-compatibility-matrix

Answer (score 6):

The "Additional property secrets is not allowed" error can be caused **either** by:

1. running Docker Engine < 1.13.1, or
2. using a compose file [version number](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#compose-and-docker-compatibility-matrix) < '3.1' in a docker-compose file such as docker-compose.yml or docker-cloud.yml

If you are experiencing this problem confirm that both are correct.

This also applies to other Docker interfaces and tools.

For examples, in Portainer, yml with secrets lines pasted into the Create Stack dialog should begin with the line `version: '3.1'` or you will encounter the same error -- even with an up-to-date Docker Engine 1.13.1+.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, Service: had an extra tab prior. Moment I removed tab prior to it, it worked.