# Docker Secrets ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, docker-compose, visual-studio-2017, docker-secrets

I want to access Docker Secrets in my ASP.Net Core project.

I distilled the issue down to a test API project. All it does is read the directories inside `/run/`

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
  return Directory.GetDirectories("/run");
}
```

I changed the compose files to **3.1** and added the plumbing for secrets listed here: [how do you manage secret values with docker-compose v3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42139605/how-do-you-manage-secret-values-with-docker-compose-v3-1/42151570)

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  secrettest:
    image: secrettest
    build:
      context: ./SecretTest
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    secrets:                    # secrets block only for 'web' service
     - my_external_secret

secrets:                        # top level secrets block
  my_external_secret:
    external: true
```

The get action returns **["/run/lock"]**. I do not see a **/run/secrets** directory. I also shelled into the container to verify it does not see the **/run/secrets** directory.

I am able to see secrets from other containers. Anyone know what I am missing? Is there another strategy I should take other than the 3.1 compose to configure the container in VS 2017?

Comment: The other containers you are shelling into and seeing secrets are created with compose as well?